# read() image file with Python and send it to HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, image, httpresponse

I am trying to return an image to HttpResponse(image_data), but I get a page contain weird symbols.
I can use PIL to .show() image perfectly from that path, but I want to display the image in browser instead of paint or an photo viewer app.

```
        image_data = open("media/hello.jpg", "rb").read()
        return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image")
```

weird symbols: ÿØÿá�Exif��II*������������ÿì�Ducky�����d��ÿî�Adobe�dÀ���ÿÛ�„�

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import FileResponse

def send_file(response):

    img = open('media/hello.jpg', 'rb')

    response = FileResponse(img)

    return response
```